# SupLat and InfLat

Tags: category-theory

I just read in [ncatlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SupLat) that SupLat and InfLat are equivalent. But, it seems to me, that they should actually be *isomorphic* categories. Am I correct or is ncatlab correct and they are not isomorphic?

Comment: Isomorphic categories are in particular equivalent. There is no contradiction.

Comment: It is not a contradiction, but isomorphism is much stronger than equivalence, so why not mention it?

Comment: @ZhenLin However what I really found a bit puzzling was the sentence about inclusion functors. It seems (to me) to say that Suplat is included in a different way than InfLat into Pos. But this is obvious, since they are different categories, they are included with different functors. So why write this down? Or does this sentence mean something else subtly different?

Comment: Well, there is the obvious inclusion and there is the non-obvious inclusion, obtained by composing with the isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, the "non obvious inclusion" is quite obvious to me. You can always compose a functor with an isomorphism (or some other functor) and get a new functor. I would not call this new functor an inclusion though, since it does not send an object to itself (CWM page 15). It is interesting to note that [inclusion functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inclusion+functor) is an empty page in ncatlab. Anyway, thank you Zhen Lin, it does not seem that I missed anything subtle on this ncatlab page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *isomorphic*: we can map the sup-lattice $(X,\le)$ to the inf-lattice $(X,\ge)$. This naturally extends on morphisms, and has a strict inverse.

Comment: thank you Berci. This is exactly what I thought. I am calling the ncatlab customer service...

Comment: Well, as ZhenLin commented, there is no contradiction here, and, probably by its nature, n-lab might not care or emphasize category isomorphisms too much..

Comment: Berci, I know, please look at the comments I wrote to Zhen Lin above